# Class IDP\Bundle\Entity\Portfolio is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to symfony2. I created a basic controller called portfolio controller and some index view for this controller. I created an Entity class as well but it gives error.

My Controller is

```
<?php
namespace IDP\Bundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 class PortfolioController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
     $product = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('IDPBundle:Portfolio')
      ->find(1);
    return $this->render('IDPBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig');
   }

}
```

Inside src/IDP/Bundle/Entity/Portfolio.php

```
 <?php
 namespace IDP\Bundle\Entity;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 class Portfolio
 {
   private $id;
   private $user_id;
   private $portfolio_name;
   private $description;
   private $permalink;
   private $sharingCode;
   private $shared;
   private $shared_portfolio_calls;
   private $patentgroup_id;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->portfolioGroups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
public function setName($portfolio_name)
{
    $this->name = $portfolio_name;
}
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
public function setSharingCode($sharingCode)
{
    $this->sharingCode = $sharingCode;
}
public function getSharingCode()
{
    return $this->sharingCode;
}
public function setShared($shared)
{
    $this->shared = $shared;
}
public function getShared()
{
    return $this->shared;
}
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
}
```

My Table name is pm_portfolios and it contains the all the field I mentioned in the Portfolio Class.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Entity class does not have any ORM metadata. Try something like this

```
 <?php

namespace IDP\Bundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 /**
 * IDP\Bundle\Entity\Portfolio
 * @ORM\Table(name="pm_portfolios")
 */
class Portfolio
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer $user_id
 */
private $user_id;

/**
 * @var string $portfolio_name
 */
private $portfolio_name;

/**
 * @var text $description
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string $permalink
 */
private $permalink;

/**
 * @var string $sharing_code
 */
private $sharing_code;

/**
 * @var boolean $shared
 */
private $shared;

/**
 * @var integer $shared_portfolio_calls
 */
private $shared_portfolio_calls;

/**
 * @var integer $patentgroup_id
 */
private $patentgroup_id;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set user_id
 *
 * @param integer $userId
 */
public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->user_id = $userId;
}

/**
 * Get user_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUserId()
{
    return $this->user_id;
}

/**
 * Set portfolio_name
 *
 * @param string $portfolioName
 */
public function setPortfolioName($portfolioName)
{
    $this->portfolio_name = $portfolioName;
}

/**
 * Get portfolio_name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPortfolioName()
{
    return $this->portfolio_name;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param text $description
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set permalink
 *
 * @param string $permalink
 */
public function setPermalink($permalink)
{
    $this->permalink = $permalink;
}

/**
 * Get permalink
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPermalink()
{
    return $this->permalink;
}

/**
 * Set sharing_code
 *
 * @param string $sharingCode
 */
public function setSharingCode($sharingCode)
{
    $this->sharing_code = $sharingCode;
}

/**
 * Get sharing_code
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSharingCode()
{
    return $this->sharing_code;
}

/**
 * Set shared
 *
 * @param boolean $shared
 */
public function setShared($shared)
{
    $this->shared = $shared;
}

/**
 * Get shared
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getShared()
{
    return $this->shared;
}

/**
 * Set shared_portfolio_calls
 *
 * @param integer $sharedPortfolioCalls
 */
public function setSharedPortfolioCalls($sharedPortfolioCalls)
{
    $this->shared_portfolio_calls = $sharedPortfolioCalls;
}

/**
 * Get shared_portfolio_calls
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getSharedPortfolioCalls()
{
    return $this->shared_portfolio_calls;
}

/**
 * Set patentgroup_id
 *
 * @param integer $patentgroupId
 */
public function setPatentgroupId($patentgroupId)
{
    $this->patentgroup_id = $patentgroupId;
}

/**
 * Get patentgroup_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPatentgroupId()
{
    return $this->patentgroup_id;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your entity lacks all the ORM metadata, like `@ORM\Entity` on the class itself and others on its properties. See [the example from the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information).